# Python selenium locate element in multiple iframes

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium for Python and was trying to locate element in multiple iframes.
This is the DOM element I can see.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>...</head>
    <body>
        <form>
        ...
           <div class="page">
               <div class="main clear" style="z-index: 20; position:relative;">
                   <div id="placeOrder">
                       <iframe src="BuyFlow.aspx" frameborder="0" width="1150" height="950">
                           #document
                               <html>
                                   <body>
                                       <form>
                                           ...
                                           <iframe id="CreativeLiftFrame">
                                               #document
                                                   <html>
                                                       ...
                                                       <body id="multiple-addresses">
                                                           ...
                                                       </body>
                                                   </html>
                                           </iframe>
                                        </form>
                                    </body>
                               </html>
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to get the `<body>` tag's `id` name of second `<iframe>`.

That's `"multiple-addresses"`.

In order to do that I have written my code as follows.

```
# Switch to the first iframe
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

# Fill in Address and ZipCode inputbox and submit form
address_input.send_keys(address)
postcode_input.send_keys(postcode)
postcode_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Check Available - Inner iframe
second_iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
driver.switch_to_frame(second_iframe)
print(second_iframe.get_attribute("id")
body = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
print(body.get_attribute("id")
```

As a result, I get 2 outputs on console.

```
CreativeLiftFrame
None
```

As you can see, selenium driver located the second `iframe`, but can't locate `body` tag's `id` in SECOND `iframe`.

I'm not sure how I can handle it.

Comment: I see two print statements in your code, and three lines of output. What is generating the error?

Comment: Hi, One is exception.

Comment: I understand, but what command is generating the exception?

Comment: I run the script as >>>python run.py. I mean the code above is snippet and the other code occurs exception.

Comment: The script you posted does not run at all ;)

Comment: What do you mean? The script consists of several files and the code above is snippet.

Comment: @A.Yagjin, can you edit your code snippet appropriately as it seem that your output does not correlate with provided code lines: note that both `print` statements have no closing bracket and it's not clear on which line you got exception...

Comment: @Andersson, please ignore the exception. All I want to know is how I can get second iframe's body tag's id.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when navigating frames in Selenium, the following method is probably most reliable.

On every single frame change, go back to the root frame, or default:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//Some XPATH here')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//Some Xpath here')))
```

In your case, switch to default, then switch to first child, then next child, and so on. On the next frame switch, repeat this - first to default, then to 1st child, etc.

I'd also add the you are searching for frames by tag_name, which is not very specific. How many tags with that tag_name are there in the whole document?

If there really is no unique `id` or `name` on that frame, you can search by the frame's `src` using something like this:

```
By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<src url here')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to retrieve the *id* of the *body* tag of the second child `<frame>` you can use the following code :

```
# Switch to the first iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='BuyFlow.aspx']")))

# Fill in Address and ZipCode inputbox and submit form
address_input.send_keys(address)
postcode_input.send_keys(postcode)
postcode_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Check Available - Inner iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"CreativeLiftFrame")))
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body'))).get_attribute("id"))
```